# Upload file from angular to Spring without configuring CORS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cors, mod-proxy

I'm trying to implement file upload using Angular. Angular is hosted on Apache server with this proxy module configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/admin>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyStatus On

    ProxyPass           /api_admin http://localhost:8080/api_admin
    ProxyPassReverse    /api_admin http://localhost:8080/api_admin
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  /api_admin /
</IfModule>
```

I use this configuration in order to host the Angular app under sub directory on Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /admin/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Typescript code for file upload:

```
imports (file: any) {
  const url = `http://111.111.111/api_admin/merchants/upload`;
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file, file.name);
  return this.http.post(url, formData);
}
```

Spring Endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/merchants")
public class MerchantController {

    @PostMapping("/upload")
        public ResponseEntity<String> uploadData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
          .........
    }
}
```

Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DbUserDetailsService dbuserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return dbuserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return dbuserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(dbuserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(dbuserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Paths:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId("resource_id").stateless(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

But I get CORS error. Usually I can open all pages and make requests to the BE but only this file upload is not working. I tried this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", methods = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.OPTIONS}, allowedHeaders = {"Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "accept", "Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"}, exposedHeaders = {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"})
@PostMapping("/upload")
            public ResponseEntity<String> uploadData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
              .........
        }
```

But again the upload request is blocked by CORS.

Do you know how I can configure Apache mod_rewrite to properly redirect the traffic?

Second way that I tried:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId("resource_id").stateless(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
        .cors().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSources() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

With the second configuration I get `has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
auth:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

What is the best way to achieve this result?

Is there some way to implement this without disabling CORS?

Comment: response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin")); - this is a really, really bad idea. especially in a global filter, since it basically completely disables any CORS checks. also: what does the preflight request actually return? you should be able to see that in your client. the error message you're quoting is just the follow-up.

Comment: I can't find more debug information. Where I can see it in Chrome?

Comment: in your developers tools on the "network" tab. if you enable the "method" column, it's easier to spot the OPTIONS request

Comment: It's OPTIONS. See this: https://ibb.co/bP9hr8S

Comment: as you can see, the status is "401" ... this means, someone is sending back "authentication" related return statuses. the only thing that would be doing that is spring security. the filter you have here is kind of in between - if you are interested in actual CORS (you should, its safer) then you need to check what spring security is doing. otherwise, you can just handle all OPTIONS requests in apache, return exactly what you're doing in your filter, and don't even pass it on to the BE.

Answer (score 0):

Few comments:

1. To resolve your issue you should use `response.setStatus(200);`
2. Your current implementation doesn't use Spring. It uses Java filters. Spring has built-in CORS handling tools, see [this](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) for example
3. Your current implementatio is not safe and is vulnerable to "CORS attacks" since you accept all origins. This allows an attacker to perform actions on behalf of your users and read their personal information. To prevent this you should check that the origin matches your origins whitelists

Comment: Thanks, I added second attempt that I tried but I get again the same error. Do you know how I can solve it?

Comment: Exactly the same error? Did you remove the filter from your code?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's also for me unknown why I get this error.

Comment: Can this be related to my setup - I use Angular 6 FE all hosted on Apache server and Spring BE on Wildfly server. Do you know do need to do also some apache or Wildfly configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You have disabled cross origin resource sharing in your ResourceSecurityConfig by configuring `.cors().disable()`. Try removing the `disable()` part and leave the `.cors()` part. This will enable CORS in the security part of your application and make it return an OK status on the preflight request.